# What is the correct AWS::Glue::Job Connections property structure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, aws-cloudformation, jobs, aws-glue

After several variations of template.json I have tried, I am still getting following error in AWS Cloudformation console:

> Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Connections} does
>   not match type {Object}]

Answer (score 10):

After debugging via boto3 in python

`glue.get_job(JobName='your job')`

we have found out that proper config is:

```
      Connections:
        Connections: 
          - 'YOUR_CONNECTION'
```

Comment: What may be the reason that it is made like this? Why would I have list of Connections and inside have list of strings?

Comment: in concept the Glue service is pretty neat but it was implemented very poorly from a UI and API design stand point

Answer (score 2):

The [answer given by viethor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59190189/11507802) is correct. But, in order make it more clear for beginners, below are further the details:

[Syntax for CloudFormation Glue Job Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC44S.png)

**JSON Example:**

```
"Connections": {
           "Connections": [
                 "YourConnectionName"
              ]
         }
```

**YAML Example:**

```
Connections:
    Connections:
         - YourConnectionName
```